# How to serve dynamic static files in express JS

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to render static file. I came across the sendFile() method but it is not working with proxy. I need help.
Here is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var process = require('process');

var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080));

app.use('$Variable',  express.static(__dirname + '$Variable'));
app.use('/', proxy(function(request, response) {
  return 'http://localhost:8000' + request.url
}))

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
app.listen(app.get('port'));
setTimeout(function() {
  process.exit();
}, 100000);
```

I want something like this does anyone has idea?
What can I do to replace the $variable with path to my files.
NOTE: $VARIABLE is just there to showcase what I am trying to mean. It does not means that I am trying to use PHP in node.js. Think before you become a professor.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  Perhaps show several examples of incoming URLs and what files in your file system you want served for each URL.  And, describe how $variable is determined.  What value does it have?

Comment: When I call /test1 i want to render /test1/webapp and When I call /test2/webapp i want to rn.der /test2/webapp. I want these links to replace $variable. there are thousands of folders like these and I can't create so many app.get call.

Comment: Is that the only value for the URL you want to serve this way or do you want to take any prefix from any URL and do that with it?  What is there's more than one part to the path like `/test1/foo`?  You really haven't specified enough info in your question for people to know how to help.  Please edit the question to include all relevant detail.

Comment: see the edited comment

Comment: I posted an answer and you suddenly went silent.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the path from the URL and append "/webapp" onto the end of it and then look for a file in your file system that matches that to serve, you could do this:

```
const path = require('path');

app.get((req, res, next) => {
    const file = path.join(__dirname, req.path, "webapp");
    res.sendFile(file, { dotfiles: "deny" }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            // decide what you want to do here with an error
            // either call next(err), call next() to continue routing
            // or send a 404 response
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    });
});
```